# error trying to use pg_size_pretty in pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm a bit new to postgres sql, so this might be an easy one, but I get an error in pgadmin4 when calling a system function:

```
    select c.relname,
           pg_size_pretty(t.table_name)
    from pg_class c
    inner join information_schema.tables t
        on c.relname = t.table_name
    where table_schema = 'public'
```

results in:

```
ERROR:  function pg_size_pretty(information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist
LINE 2:     pg_size_pretty(t.table_name)
            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 23
```

is there some particular way I need to fully qualify the function name, pgadmin4 docs aren't much help and most postgres docs assume that this would jsut work as written above...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The docs [Admin functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) will tell you the problem:

> pg_size_pretty ( bigint ) → text

> pg_size_pretty ( numeric ) → text

> Converts a size in bytes into a more easily human-readable format with size units (bytes, kB, MB, GB or TB as appropriate). Note that the units are powers of 2 rather than powers of 10, so 1kB is 1024 bytes, 1MB is 10242 = 1048576 bytes, and so on.

You need to be working on a `int` or `numeric` value not a table name.

So:

> pg_table_size ( regclass ) → bigint

> Computes the disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes (but including its TOAST table if any, free space map, and visibility map).

Which leads to:

```
select c.relname,
           pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(t.table_name::regclass))
    from pg_class c
    inner join information_schema.tables t
        on c.relname = t.table_name
    where table_schema = 'public'
```

`regclass` is used to CAST the `information_schema.sql_identifier` properly.

If you want to include the index(s) in the size then use:

> pg_total_relation_size ( regclass ) → bigint

> Computes the total disk space used by the specified table, including all indexes and TOAST data. The result is equivalent to pg_table_size + pg_indexes_size.

To simplify things:

```
select 
    relname, pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relname::regclass))
from 
    pg_class c
where 
     relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;
```

Then you are getting all the information from the system catalog and not having to join to `information_schema.tables`.

Comment: just found that in the docs myself, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the query by doing: `select c.relname, pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size(relname::regclass)) from pg_class where relnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace;`. Takes the `information_schema` out of it.